# Placing folders, inserting files, zipping all and providing download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project running.
And I have a few fundamental Ruby-On-Rails-questions on:

1. where to place a folder in my rails installation, so i have access to it from within my controllers
2. how to place files inside that folder when models are saved
3. how to zip it
4. providing the zip as a download

now, let me explain:

- I want to save to a "pages" folder that has a subfolder "blog"
- to that blog-folder I want to add subfolders each representing a post
- the name of the post-folder is created by the user, as he provides a title
- each post-folder has a MarkDown file in it called "post.md"
- if the user clicks a download-button the whole "pages"-folder should be zipped and sent to the client as a download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can put your folder anywhere, and access your .md file like following (as long as you have permission to read that file):

```
def show
    markdown=Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
    md_file = IO.read("#{Rails.root}\static\pages\blog\post.md")    
    @post = markdown.render(md_file)
end
```

and at view

```
<%= @post.html_safe %>
```

According to documentation of 'rubyzip' gem you will need something like this to make your directory zipable:

```
class ZipFileGenerator
  # Initialize with the directory to zip and the location of the output archive.
  def initialize(inputDir, outputFile)
    @inputDir = inputDir
    @outputFile = outputFile
  end
  # Zip the input directory.
  def write()
    entries = Dir.entries(@inputDir); entries.delete("."); entries.delete("..")
    io = Zip::File.open(@outputFile, Zip::File::CREATE);
    writeEntries(entries, "", io)
    io.close();
  end
  # A helper method to make the recursion work.
  private
  def writeEntries(entries, path, io)
    entries.each { |e|
      zipFilePath = path == "" ? e : File.join(path, e)
      diskFilePath = File.join(@inputDir, zipFilePath)
      puts "Deflating " + diskFilePath
      if File.directory?(diskFilePath)
        io.mkdir(zipFilePath)
        subdir =Dir.entries(diskFilePath); subdir.delete("."); subdir.delete("..")
        writeEntries(subdir, zipFilePath, io)
      else
        io.get_output_stream(zipFilePath) { |f| f.print(File.open(diskFilePath, "rb").read())}
      end
    }
  end
end
```

and at your zip action at controller:

```
directoryToZip = "/pages"
outputFile = "/public/out#{rand(6**length).to_s(6)}.zip"

zf = ZipFileGenerator.new(directoryToZip, outputFile)
zf.write()
```

and then you can provide the link of `outputFile` to your user and you may also need to delete that zip file.